# Динамическое изменение параметров запроса URL

Tags: reactjs, url

Делаю систему фильтрации на React.js (сайдбар с фильтрами, в основном состоящий из чекбоксов). При этом каталог товаров, который в будущем должен динамически реагировать на чекнутые чекбоксы и рендерить выбранные карточки товаров в силу технических особенностей на данном этапе целиком подтягивается со стороны сервера. В связи с чем, фильтрация будет работать только через динамически сформированный URL при перезагрузке страницы (Пример: `window.location.href = "?filters=" + filterName + ":" + filterItem`). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не понимаю, что я должен делать дальше, чтобы при выборе других чекбоксов, они `push/concat` к тем, что уже есть. То есть, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы, предыдущее состояние URLа сохранялось, но и добавлялось к URLу текущее состояние. 
Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: react-router используется?

Comment: используется, но здесь он ничем не сможет помочь. Так как каталог будет реагировать только на сформированный url во время перезагрузки страницы. Каталог там как цельный кусок php кода на yii

Comment: Тогда помочь не могу. Я уже не понимаю Вас и даже вникать не хочу в шаблонизацию react с помощью php. Новообще сложности нет. Парсите строку в состояние и уже его используете при инициализации ui. В чем проблема?

Comment: Пробовал парсить, но что то я делаю не так. Нет у меня опыта работы с парсингом URLa, особенно когда его значения должны динамически изменяться (добавляться новые) к уже существующим

Comment: ТогдаВам нужно задать вопрос - как создавать и изменять динамически url такого-то вида. Реакт здесь не причем. Хотя раз выиспользуете react-router, то с точки зрения реакта, очень даже причем. Но я повторюсь  - я непонимаю о чем вы говорите. Мне Ваши объяснения кажутся слегка странными. Причиной может быть то, что вы описываете свое неправильноепредставление или жея непонимаю тонкостей совместного использования реакт с php.

Comment: Сам принцип прост - при заходе на страницу вы парсите урл исоздаете значениям из него объект с помощью которого инициализируете состояние чекбоксов. Дале приизменении чекбоксов вы уже по состоянию создаете урл и полностью заменяете им ту часть, которая находится в адресной строке. Как вы её туда добавите зависит от логики работы приложения с роутером. но влюбом случаи я бы советовал делать это через react-router полученный в самом компоненте спомощью useRouter для новых и withRouter для старых версий реакта.

Comment: Осмыслю и попробую сделать так, как Вы написали. Благодарю за участие.